# Filtering out null values of object list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently filtering out null values from an array using Object.keys and map like this:

```
// The ultimate goal is to get the length of my list where !== null
var length = Object.keys(myList).map(x => myList[x]).filter(x => x !== null).length;
```

I need to find an alternative way of doing this because in IE11 I am having issues with it. It is interfering with functionality of a 3rd party control somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the better approach would be to see how this can affect the other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not supported in IE. So , the equivalent of your code is:

```js
var myList = {'1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': null};
var length =   Object.keys(myList).map(function (x) {
  return myList[x]
}).filter(function (x) {
  return x !== null;
}).length;

console.log(length);
```

Because the output of Object.keys(myList) is an array and you need only to filter elements by their vaues (not null) you may reduce all to:

```js
var myList = {'1': '11', '2': '22', '3': '33', '4': null};
var length =   Object.keys(myList).filter(function (x) {
  return myList[x] !== null;
}).length;

console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var length = 0

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  if (myList[i] !== null) { 
     length++; 
  } 
}
```

In this case, the `for-loop` is your `map` and the `if-condition` is your `filter`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. Thanks!